# .Net Serilog Email

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I have a C# .net 5 web app  and API that I am trying to add Serilog into. I have the serilog sinks for both email and ms sql working but the emails appear to only send when using Log directly. This is what I have (some items not shown for brevity):

In Program.cs

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            BuildConfig(builder);
            Log.Logger = CreateLogger(builder);

            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Fatal(e, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        public static Serilog.ILogger CreateLogger(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var emailSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("WriteTo").GetSection("0").GetSection("Args");
            var emailInfo = CreateEmailInformation(emailSettings);

            return new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                       .WriteTo.Email(emailInfo)
                       .CreateLogger();
        }
```

So above the Log.Fatal(...) does send an email however in the below API service _logger does not send an email:

```
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<CollectionRepository> _logger;

        public CollectionRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext, ILogger<CollectionRepository> logger)
        {
            _context = appDbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<List<amp.collection>> GetCollections()
        {
            var result = new List<amp.collection>();
            try
            {
                result = await db.GetCollections();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Exception occurred in GetCollections()");
            }
            return result;
        }
```

What am I missing for why the _logger is not sending out emails?

**Update**
The issue appears to be because of the async of emails. After testing and adding a Log.CloseAndFlush() immediately after the _logger.Error() the email gets sent.

Comment: First of all have you tried log.fatal in Repository replacing log.error?

Comment: @AliK I have tried both Log.Error() and Log.Fatal() in placed of the _logger.LogError line and neither sent an email.

Comment: In `var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); BuildConfig(builder);`, you seem to be dropping the builder that has the UseSerilog configured in the pipeline. I would take out the email etc, make it work correctly with just File/Console, and then get the email wired in and/or configured rather than trying to do it all at once

Comment: @RubenBartelink The only thing that doesn't make sense with that is that it is writing to the sql database in all instances of _logger.Error() or Log.Error()/Log.Fatal(). If the builder wasn't properly configured I would think that it wouldn't be writing to the sql database during _logger.Error either.

Comment: @RubenBartelink But I did check and the _logger.LogError() lines do successfully write to a log file...but no email

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested if this makes any difference. But at least this is how I set it up:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseSerilog();
        });
```

There's an example that I know works with `ILogger` here (for inspiration): https://github.com/elmahio/serilog-sinks-elmahio/tree/main/examples/Serilog.Sinks.ElmahIo.AspNetCore31

Comment: This doesn't appear to make a difference.